# Call to undefined function svn_auth_set_parameter() in php

Tags: php, svn

While I trying connect svn using php svn package in windows xampp and I got the below error.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function svn_auth_set_parameter()

I have followed
https://www.php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php manual and installed svn module in php and enabled `extension=php_svn` in php.ini file.

Here the sample code I have used

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, 'my username');
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, 'password');
```